# EF6 MySQL EDM закрывается окно

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

Установил `EF6`, хочу создать модель на основе уже существующей базы данных. 
Выбивает `EDM` на моменте когда появляется окно с выбором версии `EF6.0`.
Гугл дал пару ответов, выполнил их, не помогло, что я сделал:

Полностью удалил все ссылки и установил их по очереди:

```
- MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6;
- MySQL.Data;
- Entity Framework;
```

Так же добавил в `app.config`:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Есть еще идеи, как решить проблему?

Comment: зачем вам это `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer` ?

Comment: да видел, удалял их. Не помогало.

Comment: Ваша проблема похожа вот на [это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50874607/312041)

Comment: увы, проблему не решаема..